# Want to install PHP 7.3 on a VM with no internet access

Tags: virtual-machine, centos, php

I have a VM operating on centos7 and I have been told to install PHP 7.3 on it.
But the main issue with it is that it doesn't have access to the internet.

so if anyone knows how to install it without having access to the internet, do reply with each step.

Comment: Bring over the PHP installation on removable media, or use a CentOS installation media.

Comment: We are using a cloud service.

Comment: How are you using a cloud VM without internet? You will need to upload the installation.

Comment: Through a VPN and thanx mate problem has been solved.